# allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true not working in xcode 7.1

Tags: ios, xcode, wkwebview

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

var webView : WKWebView!

override func loadView() {
    webView = WKWebView()
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    self.view = webView
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = NSURL(string: "http://boooo.com")
    webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url!))
    webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true



}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}


}
```

Everything works fine but allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true not working in xcode 7.1. can't go back and forward in wkwebview.

Answer (score 3):

Look like it's interfering with navigationController's **interactivePopGestureRecognizer** (if you have one).

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = true
}
```

So I just **disabled this property** at the time of using WKWebView in navigation stack!